# What is a good method/technique in investigating an error in a huge log file?

Tags: debugging, logging

I'm received the task to investigate a few huge log files with 10.000+ lines of logs for an error. How would you start with this, are there any recommended steps/techniques/methods that can help with a task like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can export logs in an excel. Then try to filter columns by creation date for example or with something that is going to be closer to the error that you are trying to find.

Comment: That's actually a great suggestion!

Comment: @depotter If you want make this answer as useful/accepted in order to help others too. Thanks